# Script to Extract data from web page

Tags: python

I am looking to extract some parts of data rendered on a web page.
I am able to pull the entire data from the page and save it in a text file (RAW) using the code below.

```
curl http://webpage -o "raw.txt"
```

Just wondering if there were other alternatives and advantages whatsoever.

Comment: You could use Python's urllib2 module, and then BeautifulSoup to extract what you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use a combination of [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html), and [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests    
    
session = requests.session()    
req = session.get('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807081/script-to-extract-data-from-wbpage')    
doc = BeautifulSoup(req.content)    
print(doc.findAll('a', { "class" : "gp-share" }))
```

Comment: I had to remove the specific URL and parsing by request from the company running that site. Just leaving a comment here as a heads up.

Answer (score 1):

cURL is a good start. A better command line will be :

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0" -L -k -b /tmp/c -c /tmp/c -s http://url.tld
```

because it plays with cookies, user-agent, SSL certificates and others things.

See `man curl`

Answer (score 1):

1. **Save / Process a Single Web Resource:** The above approach is good for a single file/web resource. Also you can pipe a regex and chop/skip data based on a preset pattern. eg: save all the  tag
   source urls.
2. **Save / Process Entire Directory or a Website Recursively:** Use a Python or Perl script which can iteratively pull down all the links
   and resources belonging to a page or a website dns name. In Python I
   would use http lib and parse the tags recursively (make sure to have a depth limit or with a large website you might end up saving gigs of data!). An easy and safe bet is [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) - which is a Python library that can scrap web data, navigate, seearch a parse tree of a remote web resource. Also it can modify the parsed local contents, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code will fetch all data from the web page. If you want to parse the web page and extract specific information I suggest that you use some existing parser.

I usually use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for extracting data from html pages.